# Apollo-client: Add item to array in cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Suppose I have the following GraphQL types:

```apollo
type User {
  id: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
  id: String!
  text: String,
}
```

And here is a mutation that returns the updated post:

```apollo
mutation addNewPost(
  $userId: String!
  $text: String!
) {
  addNewPost(userId: $userId, text: $text) {
    id
    text
  }
}
```

After running this mutation my cache contains a new entry of a post. How do I add it to the user's posts array? I have tried [cache.writeQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#combining-reads-and-writes) and [cache.modify](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#cachemodify) but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: update after mutation is described in docs

Answer (score 5):

We do push the item into array inside the update function, which is one of the options of useMutation.
I'm writing the whole mutation  so that you can get the idea , let have a look at example:

**By Update function:**

```
const [createPost, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST, {
  update(cache, response) {

  // Here we write the update

  // Step 1: Read/Fetch the data   
  const data = client.readQuery({
    query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
  });

  // Step 2: Update the cache by immutable way   
  client.writeQuery({
    query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
    data: {
      getPosts: [response.data.createPost, ...data.getPosts],
    },
  });
 },
    variables: formValues,
  });
```

**By refetchQueries:**
That's really shortcut  way to update the cache, by using DocumentNode object parsed with the gql function

```
const [createPost, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST, {
   
    refetchQueries: [                         
               FETCH_POSTS_QUERY
              'fetchPosts`' // OR  Query name
   ],   
     
    variables: formValues,
  });
```

Comment: Good answer :) deserves to be accepted.

Comment: Small typo, `client` should be `cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to directly write to the Apollo cache in order to update the other entities that your mutation has modified.

Have a look at the docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates here for specifics (you're going to want to use `cache.modify` and `cache.writeFragment`)